# Parameter naming on route::controller in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm using the controller functionality of Laravel 5 as follows:

```
Route::controller('somename', '\App\Http\Controllers\SomeController', [
    'someMethod' => 'some.name'
]);

class SomeController extends Controller {

    public function getSomeMethod($param) {
    } 

}
```

Now I would like to execute that method through some ajax request from a blade template. For this I'm using the jQuery ajax method as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: laroute.route('some.name', {param: 'someValue'})
});
```

This will not work because 'param' is not a bound parameter. If I use:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: laroute.route('some.name', {one: 'someValue'})
});
```

it works. How can I name the parameter (while still using `Route::controller`) so that laroute also knows about the name of the parameter and I won't have to use `one`, `two`, `three` as parameter name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route::controller does not support this kind of parameter binding. You shouldn't use Route::controller anymore as it will be removed in Laravel 5.2.